# Updating the LaunchConfigurationDialog from a launch delegate tab in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my eclipse plugin, I have created a launch delegate that gets attached to  the LocalJavaApplication launcher as a new tab in its LaunchConfiguration dialog.

The new LaunchConfigurationTab has a check box in it, and once clicked, I would like to update the VMArguments text in the ArgumentsLaunchConfigurationTab of the dialog with some extra VM parameters.

I have managed to update and save the data for the configurations associated with the LaunchConfigurationDialog. But an update to the VM Arguments text only becomes visible after I close the configuration dialog and re-open it.

I haven't been able to find a method that refreshes the view for the given tab once the associated text is updated. Can anyone tell me whether or not it is possible, and how so?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

Seems like in **LaunchConfigurationsDialog** while **performApply** allows for propagating changes from the GUI to the configuration, **initializeForm** does the opposite and updates the GUI from the configuration info.

This reference does a good job describing the details: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html